# In a dual boot, why can I see and mount the Windows partition, labeled 'OS'?

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem

Does it present a security threat in any form?

Comment: He. People here usually complain if they can't see it. As for the label, many OEMs label the Windows partition as "OS".

Comment: Please describe, where or at what point during boot you can see the Windows partition.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, my windows installation is mounted under /media/<username>

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the point, that you refer to in your question, where it's labelled "OS".

Comment: Oh wait, is the file system on the Windows partition labelled "OS"? You can find out with `sudo lsblk -f` (column `LABEL`).

Comment: Yes, it's labeled 'OS' - for instance I can see this under mounted devices in the file manager

Answer (score 0):

Not really a security threat; ubuntu comes with ntfs-3g by default so it can read/mount ntfs partitions from the get go. Granted, one could use your linux partition to nuke the windows partition, but that's on you, not the os. Secure both OSs and the issue is nonexistant :)